# Angular material table show different colored icons based on data

Tags: angular-material

I'm using Angular Material Table to show some date on my page. What I want to do is to modify the received data, what I get from backend is 3 different letters, A: answered, Y: yes, N: no. I want to show these as different color icons in the table not just letters, like A is a green tick and N is red x mark. How can I format it to show the icons and not the letters?

here's my code:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">

<mat-card>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="answer">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <h3>Answered</h3>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.answer}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  

 
  <!-- (page)="onPaginate($event)" -->
  <mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]" showFirstLastButtons [pageSize]="pageSize  || defaultPageSize">
  </mat-paginator>

</mat-card>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *ngIf in your cell to display whatever HTML you want:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
  <img *ngIf="element.answer === 'A'" src="...">
  <div *ngIf="element.answer === 'B'">the answer is B</div>
  <mat-icon *ngIf="element.answer === 'C'">home</mat-icon>
</td>
```